# Helm change name of deployments artiefacts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I’ve created helm chart which is working as expected, however I want to change the names of the deployed 
application
currently for each deployment I got different (random) name and I want it to be a fixed name, how can I do that?

This is the helper

```
{{/* vim: set filetype=mustache: */}}
{{/*
Expand the name of the chart.
*/}}
{{- define "unleash.name" -}}
{{- default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}

{{/*
Create a default fully qualified app name.
We truncate at 63 chars because some K8S name fields are limited to this (by the DNS naming spec).
*/}}
{{- define "unleash.fullname" -}}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

This is the outcome of the name after deployment

```
crabby-ibex-postgresql-0              0/1    Pending            0         1s
crabby-ibex-unleash-86775cdffd-xt575  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         1s
```

This is the names from the values yaml

```
replicaCount: 1
namespace: unleash
restartPolicy: Never
name: a-unleash
nameOverride: unleash
```

e.g. I want it instead of

```
crabby-ibex-unleash-86775cdffd-xt575
```

to be like

```
unleash-service
uleash-postgressql
```

**update**

I've added the following to the `_helper.tpl`

```
{{- if .Values.fullnameOverride -}}
{{- .Values.fullnameOverride | trunc 26 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

and put the following in the `values.yml`
`fullnameOverride: apps`

i expect that the artifacts will start with `apps` and it doesnt work

Comment: You can specify the Pod names only if you create Pod directly not use controllers like Deployment or Statefulset.

Comment: @wineinlib - thanks, can you specifiy and example what should I change?

Comment: In your examples, `crabby-ibex-postgresql` and `crabby-ibex-unleash` are deployed using Statefulset and Deployment respectively(see files in `templates/`). AFAIK, you can specify the Statefulset and Deployment name but not the names of Pod they controll. You can specify Pod names if you change Statefulset and Deployment to Pod, which is not a good practice. Why do you need to specify the Pod names? need to use them later? There are other ways to get them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based of name `crabby-ibex-unleash-86775cdffd-xt575` I guess you are using `kind: Deployment` for this application, if you change `kind` to `StatefulSet` in you yaml you will end up with pod named `uleash-postgressql-0`, but because of helm you have additional prefix, you could use `--name=you_relese_name` which will create pod `you_relese_name-uleash-postgressql-0`.

If you really want to get rid of helm chart prefix you have to set `fullnameOverride` for every chart you are deploying.

EDIT:
To make use of `fullnameOverride` you have to define it in your `_helpers.tpl` file.

```
{{/* vim: set filetype=mustache: */}}
{{/*
Expand the name of the chart.
*/}}
{{- define "unleash.name" -}}
{{- default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
{{/*
Create a default fully qualified app name.
We truncate at 63 chars because some K8S name fields are limited to this (by the DNS naming spec).
*/}}
{{- define "unleash.fullname" -}}
{{- if .Values.fullnameOverride -}}
{{- .Values.fullnameOverride | trunc 26 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- else -}}
{{- $name := default .Chart.Name .Values.nameOverride -}}
{{- printf "%s-%s" .Release.Name $name | trunc 63 | trimSuffix "-" -}}
{{- end -}}
```

Comment: Thanks, you said to use `fullnameOverride` can I use it on the values.yaml or should I pass it as argumates

Comment: You can use it in values.yaml or using `--set fullnameOverride` results will be the same.

Comment: I've put it in the values yaml and it didnt work...any idea?

Comment: `nameOverride` and `fullnameOverride` it is not the same

Comment: the `nameOverride` is already working but the `fullnameOverride` doesnt change anything, any idea?

Comment: You have to define it in your _helpers.tpl, check [this](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/prometheus-operator/templates/_helpers.tpl#L15)

Comment: Thanks, please see my update maybe I miss something

Comment: `fullnameOverride` must be a part of `{{- define "unleash.name" -}}`

Answer (score 2):

I don't know, why nobody posted it yet. You can pass the name of the Helm release to the `helm install` command:

`helm install <your_Chart.yaml_directory> -n <release_name>`